# Is there a simple way to prove the Brouwer fixed Point theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

The quest may be for references but I want to know if there is a simple way to prove the Brouwer fixed point theorem!

That is if a function $f:\bar{B}\to\bar{B}$ is continuous then $f$ admits one fixed point!

The answer for the $R¹$ is a real analysis exercise and it also holds for any interval compact!

The proof is related with Schauder fixed-point theorem?

Comment: It's false for $\mathbb R$. Take $f(x)=x+1$. It's certainly true for compact intervals though.

Comment: yeah the interval has to be compact, sorry for the distraction!

Comment: You like to use exclamation points! :)

Comment: The number of exclamation marks probably means that you're very excited! So I'm sure you have looked at the extensive [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem)! Why do the references and proofs given there not answer your question? @Jim: och, you beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [book proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=KvQr9l0wgf8C&pg=PA148) using [Sperner's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma) which is (very!) elegant and (IMO) simple.

Comment: This one is nice! Fast answer ;-)

Comment: @Aryabhata: you are missing an exclamation mark somewhere!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thanks! Corrected :-)